# Hair simulation cache

Tags: particles, hair, cache

I am trying to cache a heavy hair simulation (picture and blend file below). I have two problems:

1. I tried to cache "in file" by disabling the "disk cache" box. The file seems to be getting bigger and bigger. It's been cached and uncached a couple of times. Is there a way to reset the whole caching process without recreating it from scratch?
2. Very often the simulation just wont work. When I append it from another scene it works, But if I change it's settings it stops working.

[image: These are the settings.]

[This is the blender file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-_mQmsdsEpnSmd5ekRUenVLNTQ/view?usp=sharing) A bit large (125mb) I know :( hence the first question.